# How to log authorization errors from an authenticated user?

Tags: samba

I use Samba 3.6.6 in conjunction with Windows10.  User share read and write on a SMB share.

Sometimes users receive message that prevent them from deleting folders, such as  "You do not have the permission to perform this action".

How can i log those messages on the server?

Comment: Are you seeing any logs from your samba? For instance, if you run `journalctl -xeu smb`?

Comment: I am using Samba 3.6.6 on an old Linux, so there is no `systemd` in it.  But I can say for sure, that those events are currently not logged.